# MongoDB Count with Limit

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've built a report that fetches paginated result sets using the MongoDB aggregation pipeline like this:

```
$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => $this->_queryOptions),
    array('$skip' => $this->_startingIndex),
    array('$group' => array(
            "_id" => array(
                'username' => '$username',
                'prefix' => '$prefix',
                'claimNumber' => '$claimNumber'
            ),
            "viewCount" => array('$sum' => 1),
            "timestamp" => array('$max' => '$timestamp'),
            "companyNumber" => array('$addToSet' => '$companyNumber'),
            "policyNumber" => array('$addToSet' => '$policyNumber')
        )
    ),
    array('$sort' => array($sortBy => $this->_sortDir)),
    array('$limit' => $this->_limit)
    );

$results = $this->_collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

This is working as expected. However, I'm struggling with getting a total count (just for the purposes of the pagination display) ... as if I were to run the query without the limit and do a `count($results['result'])`

Does anyone know of an efficient way to do this, given that the aggregate() method returns raw data and not a cursor object?

Thanks in advanced for any feedback!